# Round each column in df1 based on corresponding column in df2

Tags: python, pandas

df1:

| Li | Be | Sc | V | Cr | Mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.1564 | -0.0011 | -0.1921 | 0.0343 | 0.5729 | 0.1121 |
| 19.2871 | -0.0027 | 0.0076 | 0.066 | 0.5196 | 0.0981 |
| 0.8693 | 0.0016 | 0.1997 | 0.0317 | 0.0533 | 0.014 |

df2:

| Li | Be | Sc | V | Cr | Mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.0 | 0.050 | 0.3 | 0.111 | 0.50 | 0.40 |

I need to round the columns in df1 to the same number of decimals places as the corresponding columns in df2. The issue is that each df contains 40+ columns all needing to be rounded to a specific number of decimal places.

I can do this column by column like

```
df1["Li"]=df1["Li"].round(1)
df1["Be"]=df1["Be"].round(3)
etc
```

Is there an easier way to round all the columns in df1 based on the number of decimals in df2

desired output:

| Li | Be | Sc | V | Cr | Mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.2 | -0.001 | -0.2 | 0.034 | 0.57 | 0.11 |
| 19.3 | -0.003 | 0 | 0.066 | 0.52 | 0.1 |
| 0.9 | 0.002 | 0.2 | 0.032 | 0.05 | 0.01 |

Comment: Can you provide a constructor for df2?  Are those floats or strings?

Comment: @ScottBoston they are floats

Comment: There is no such thing as `0.100` in python, `round(0.1, 3)` -> `0.1`, if you want to ensure a formatting you have to use strings

Comment: @mozway I am aware. It is just an example. I need the numbers to be floats

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Decimal` from `decimal` module to get the exponent part and use `.round` with a mapping dict to convert all columns:

```
from decimal import Decimal

exponent = lambda x: abs(Decimal(str(x)).as_tuple().exponent)
rounding = df2.T.squeeze().map(exponent)

out = df1.round(rounding)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Li   Be   Sc      V   Cr   Mn
0  20.2 -0.0 -0.2  0.034  0.6  0.1
1  19.3 -0.0  0.0  0.066  0.5  0.1
2   0.9  0.0  0.2  0.032  0.1  0.0

>>> rounding
Li    1
Be    2
Sc    1
V     3
Cr    1
Mn    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

**Note**: as @mozway suggested you, `0.050` has only 2 decimals not 3 because python doesn't care about trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

This could not be a very standard way to convert data to the desired form but it might solve your purpose.

```
for i in df2.columns:
    a = str(df2[i][0])
    df1[i] = df1[i].round(len(a.split('.')[1]))
```